# "Run" menu is placed before other menus in an Eclipse RCP IDE project

Tags: eclipse, menu, ide, action, rcp

I have developed a IDE for a custom language in Eclipse 3 for RCP and RAP developers. Therefore I used IDE plug-ins wherever possible and applicable. This week I was busy migrating the application to Eclipse e4 (with compatibility layer) with Eclipse for RCP and RAP developers 2021-6. Everything works nearly fine so far.

The one thing i cannot figure out is how I can place the "run" menu where I want. It is placed as first menu in the menu bar.

Another strange thing by the way is that if I use Eclipse 2020-6 instead of 2021-6 as development environment, also the search menu is at the wrong position.

The problem is that the run and search menus come from an IDE plug-in and they are implemented as actions and therefore I cannot specify any order in terms of menus. For all other menus I defined appropriate `menuContibution`s, commands and handlers. For the latter, I can decide where each menu should be placed with the help of plugin.xml by specifying `?before=` or `?after=`.

I did a search over stackoverflow issues that have to do with adding menus, reorderung menus, mixing actions with commands and handlers and so on but I could not find a solution how I could place the run menu where I want.

I hoped that there would be something like an ID that I can use to specify as `?before=` or `?after=` in plugin.xml but I think this will not work with actions.

Can anyone give me a hint how I could place all menus in the desired order? Or is this simply impossible when mixing actions and commands+handlers? Is there any actions-wrapping functionality in order for me to specify `?before=` or `?after=` in my `menuContibution`s in plugin.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the Run menu added by the `org.eclipse.debug.ui` plug-in this is created using and action set:

```xml
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.actionSets">
        <actionSet
            label="%BreakpointActionSet.label"
            visible="false"
            id="org.eclipse.debug.ui.breakpointActionSet">
         <menu
               label="%RunMenu.label"
               path="additions"
               id="org.eclipse.ui.run">
```

which is adding the Run menu at the position `additions` in the main menu.

The standard main menu created by `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder` creates the main menu like this:

```java
@Override
protected void fillMenuBar(IMenuManager menuBar) {
    menuBar.add(createFileMenu());
    menuBar.add(createEditMenu());
    menuBar.add(createNavigateMenu());
    menuBar.add(createProjectMenu());

    // This line creates the 'additions' position
    menuBar.add(new GroupMarker(IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS));

    menuBar.add(createWindowMenu());
    menuBar.add(createHelpMenu());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to greg-449, I finally figured it out. The following definition finally solved my problem (--> `?before=org.eclipse.ui.run`):

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu?before=org.eclipse.ui.run">
     <menu
           id="at.boi.tabex.dvl.mainmenu.file"
           label="&amp;File">
     </menu>
     <menu
           id="at.boi.tabex.dvl.mainmenu.edit"
           label="&amp;Edit">
     </menu>
     <menu
           id="at.boi.tabex.dvl.mainmenu.project"
           label="&amp;Project">
     </menu>
     <menu
           id="at.boi.tabex.dvl.mainmenu.tools"
           label="&amp;Tools">
     </menu>
     <menu
           id="at.boi.tabex.dvl.mainmenu.table"
           label="&amp;Ta&amp;ble">
     </menu>
  </menuContribution>
</extension>
```